# Structure UITableView with custom iPod Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, ipod

I having a problem trying to display albums & respective songs by certain artist in a tableView, separating the Albums title by section's and the songs in the rows.

I'm using this code to make an NSArray with all albums by this certain artist:

```
 - (NSArray *)getAlbumsMatchingQuery:(NSString *)query
{
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artistNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:query forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    MPMediaQuery *albumQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:[NSSet setWithObject:artistNamePredicate]];
    [albumQuery setGroupingType:MPMediaGroupingAlbum];

    /** each index of this array contains a media item collection. 
        each collection contains the media items from the iPod library by a particular artist.
        the elements of the array are sorted by album name.
    **/
    NSArray *albums = [albumQuery collections];

    NSMutableArray *arrayAlbums = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (MPMediaItemCollection *album in albums) {
        MPMediaItem *representativeItem = [album representativeItem];
        [arrayAlbums addObject:representativeItem];
    }
    return arrayAlbums;
}
```

Now I don't know how to display that structure in my tableview separating by the album title and respective songs.

Any suggestions is valid, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol in your view controller.

Specify number of sections with `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. This will be the number of unique albums in your array. Optionally, title each section with `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:`.

Then you can use `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` for the number of songs in that album, and `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to put together a cell for each song.

You may want to use `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` to title the header with the artist's name.

By the way you can read all this [in the iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

However since you're structuring your data so, maybe it would be better to use a jagged 2D array--basically an array of albums, each album is its own array of songs--or better yet structure it with your own classes. Imagine an `Artist` object that has an array of `Album` objects, each having an album title and an array of `Song` objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm familiarized with UITableViewDataSource, my problem is this structure that you talked about, an jagged 2D array. Do you mind to give me some simple examples in code, please? I'm really stuck in this...

Comment: Did you try [Googling it?](https://www.google.com/search?q=jagged+nsarray&gws_rd=ssl#q=jagged+array+objective+c) There's nothing to stop you from putting a handful of `NSArray` in an `NSArray`. Or, as you have, using `NSMutableArray`.